# Do not include vendor folder into webpack / Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

*Edit: Typescript has her own configuration via tsconfig.json and there I had to add the vendor folder.*

I have a folder structure like:

`misc/config/base.js
misc/template.ejs
sources/scripts/...
sources/styles/...
vendor/...`

and my webpack config looks like:

```
    entry: [
        path.join(paths.scripts.path, paths.scripts.file),
        path.join(paths.styles.path, paths.styles.file),
    ],
    output: {
        path: paths.build.path,
        filename: paths.build.files.script,
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.scss'],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(tsx|ts)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                // transformation order is from down to up
                loaders: [
                    'babel?'+JSON.stringify({
                        presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
                        plugins: [babelRelayPlugin],
                    }),
                    'ts'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', ['css', 'postcss', 'sass']),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=100000&name=./css/fonts/font-[hash].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=100000&name=./img/[ext]/img-[hash].[ext]',
            },
        ],
    },
```

Everytime I do start webpack dev server it complains about ts and d.ts (typescript files) but actually it should not touch vendor at all. How can I achieve this?

Edit: Almost all error that I get are of the shape like:
`ERROR in /.../vendor/postgraphql/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
(165,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'String'.`

Comment: As I understood webpack starts with the entry points and resolves every require and import statement and transpiles all found files. But my vendor folder has no require call in the scripts or sources folder. So the entrypoints can't link to it. Why does try webpack to do something with it?

Comment: try `exclude: /(node_modules|vendor)/,`

Comment: Does not work. The ts-loader I guess is still inspecting the vendor folder ERROR in /.../vendor/postgraphql/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts
(3040,10): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HexBase64BinaryEncoding'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript has her own configuration via tsconfig.json and there I had to add the vendor folder.

```
    "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "vendor"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's the babel loader complaining here trying to parse your vendor files.  If that's the case (hard to be sure without seeing the error), then changing that loader object to this should help:

```
{
    test: /\.(tsx|ts)$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /vendor/],
    // transformation order is from down to up
    loaders: [
        'babel?'+JSON.stringify({
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: [babelRelayPlugin],
        }),
        'ts'],
},
```

Comment: Does not work. The ts-loader I guess is still inspecting the vendor folder ERROR in /.../vendor/postgraphql/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts (3040,10): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HexBase64BinaryEncoding'.